# How can I rewrite pushing certain elements of a Javascript array into a new array in Lodash?

Tags: lodash

List item

I am trying to rewrite this specific logic from Javascript to
    Lodash. 
        I want to try to stay away from using the push function, so that when 
        I create a new array with less element then the original array (only 
        copying certain elements of the array instead of the whole array) 
        then I will obtain the same result.

````
    Here is an example in Javascript that I would like to rewrite in 
    Lodash 
    to avoid using push.the original example array would have more 
    key:value elments

    ```javascript
    let exampleArray = {};
    let newExampleArray = [];
````

for (var i = 0; i < this.exampleArray.length; i++) {

```
    var feed = {
    id: this.exampleArray[i].id,
    field1: this.exampleArray[i].field1,
    field2: this.exampleArray[i].field2,
    field3: this.exampleArray[i].field3,
    field4: this.exampleArray[i].field4, 
    sampleId: this.exampleArray[i].sampleId,
    active: this.exampleArray[i].active
    };

    //Passing Json Feed into the new Array
    newExampleArray.push(feed);
```

}
        I have tried using push method in Javascript which worked. Lodash
        functions map, reduce, spread, and compact did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do but...

```
exampleArray.forEach( ({ id, field1, field2, field3, field4, sampleId, active }) => 
newExampleArray.push({id, field1, field2, field3, field4, sampleId, active}));
```

same result in one line, or...

```
exampleArray.forEach( ({ unwantedField1, unwantedField2, ...rest }) => newExampleArray.push(rest));
```

or

```
newExampleArray = exampleArray.map(({ unwantedField1, unwantedField2, ...rest }) => rest )
```

all assuming that this `exampleArray = {};` is a typo and meant `let exampleArray = [];`

This is all es6 js, no Lodash required